# Why can we separate the radial and angular dependence for the eigenstates of this Hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, linear-algebra, differential-equations

In other words, how can we be sure that all of the solutions must be separable? The Hamiltonian is the one given for a single particle in a central potential: (the reduced form for the simple 2-body  Hamiltonian)
$$
\hat{H}=\frac{\hat{\mathbf{p}}^{2}}{2 \mu}+V(|\hat{\mathbf{r}}|)
$$

From text:

One of the most evident features of the position-space representations (9.117), (9.127), and (9.128) of the angular momentum operators is that they depend only on the angles $\theta$ and $\phi$, not at all on the magnitude $r$ of the position vector. Rotating a position eigenstate changes its direction but not its length. Thus we can isolate the angular dependence and determine $\langle\theta, \phi \mid l, m\rangle$, the amplitude for a state of definite angular momentum to be at the angles $\theta$ and $\phi$. These amplitudes, which are functions of the angles, are called the spherical harmonics and denoted by
$$
\langle\theta, \phi \mid l, m\rangle=Y_{l, m}(\theta, \phi)
$$
Expressed in terms of these amplitudes, the energy eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian (9.57) are given by
$$
\langle r, \theta, \phi \mid E, l, m\rangle=R(r) Y_{l, m}(\theta, \phi)
$$

I cannot quite understand the argument here. How is the fact "Rotating a position eigenstate changes its direction but not its length." and the fact that the generator of these rotations are angular momentum operators imply that the energy eigenstates must be separable?

I can include further details if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

We know the eigenstates can be separable because we can decompose the equation into two independent components - the angular and the radial one. They are *independent* because rotation doesn't affect the radial part. In that sense, it is not different than saying that if we can decompose the equation into two independent components - one only depending on $x$ and the other on the $y$ coordinate, than there exist a set of solutions which is separable in $x$ and $y$. That is because translations in $x$ do not affect the $y$ coordinate and vice-versa.

Mathematicaly, we can see it in the following way: we have an equation $H\Psi(\vec{r}) = E\psi(\vec{r})$ where $H$ is some differential operator, and we find out that we can decompose it into
$$ E\Psi(\vec{r}) = H_{\rm ang}\Psi(\vec{r}) + H_{\rm radial}\Psi(\vec{r}) $$
where $H_{\rm ang}$ only affects the angles and $H_{\rm radial}$ only affects the radial part. Then we can use an *ansatz* of separable solution $\Psi(\vec{r}) = f(r)\Theta(\theta, \varphi)$ and get that the equation now reads
$$ E f(r) \Theta(\theta, \varphi) = f(r) H_{\rm ang}\Theta(\theta, \varphi) + \Theta(\theta, \varphi) H_{\rm radial}f(r)$$ we can divide by $\Psi = f\Theta$ and get
$$ E = \frac{H_{\rm ang}\Theta(\theta, \varphi)}{\Theta(\theta, \varphi)} + \frac{H_{\rm radial}f(r)}{f(r)}$$
the left hand side is constant, so if we change $\theta, \varphi$ only the first term on the right-hand-side can change, but it should still maintain the equation, so it must be constant as well, and likewise if we change only $r$. So both the terms on the right-hand-side are constant, and we can solve them separately. The fact that we can change one of the parts without affecting the other one is crucial here. Without that, we wouldn't be able to get to the conclusion that each of the is constant.

Also note, that this means that **there is** a set of solution of separable form. There might be other sets of solution (assuming that there is a degeneracy and the set of solutions is not unique) which will not be separable along these lines. An example of that you can get when examining the $2d$ harmonic oscillator:
$$ H = \frac{p_x^2 + p_y^2}{2m} + \frac{1}{2}m\omega^2(x^2+y^2)$$
you can separate it on $x$ and $y$ and get one set of solutions, or go to radial coordinates and separate is on $r$ and $\varphi$ and get another set of solutions. Both of these sets are valid, and related to one another by a change of basis transformation.

Comment: So, we obtained _a_ set of solutions after using the ansatz that it is separable. Okay, so there do exist separable solutions. But that there might exist some solutions that are not separable, right? If so, then why are we not interested in those solutions?

Comment: Assuming that a set of solutions are separable and then obtaining them cannot prove that every solution must indeed be separable.

Comment: no: there might be solutions that are not separable (as in the 2d harmonic oscillator case, for example), but the set of separable solutions is a complete basis, and any solution can be written as a superposition of separable solutions

Comment: I can see why any superposition would be a solution, but I cannot quite see why they form a complete basis. Could you elaborate?

Comment: for example, in the 2d harmonic oscillator example: working in the $x-y$ basis, we can write a solution such as $(|n_x = 2, n_y = 0\rangle + |n_x = 0, n_y = 2\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$, which is no longer separable in $x-y$, but itself is a valid eigenstate of the Hamiltonian. The point is that the separation gives a complete basis to expand all solutions in

Comment: how are we convinced that the set of solutions that are separable form a _complete basis_?

Comment: I found relevant posts: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1163773/when-does-separation-of-variables-yield-basis-of-solution-set & https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1166117/completeness-of-solutions-and-the-separation-of-variables-method

Comment: @curiouss. [Sturm-Liouville Theory is a start](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory).  The point is that this stuff has been figured out, and most physicists just use it.

Comment: @march Sturm-Liouville theory is about ODEs, while separation of variables is about PDEs.

Comment: @Ruslan.  Sure, that's why it's a *start*. When PDEs are separable, they can often (in part) be reduced to Sturm-Liouville problems, and so part of the completeness of the resulting separable solutions to the PDE comes from there.  It's not the end of the story, and even linear homogeneous PDE's are hard, but I don't think the OP wants the whole story about proving the completeness of the separable solutions. But maybe they do.

Comment: @yyy the fact that the set of separable solutions is a complete basis is due to the fact that $H_{ang}$ and $H_{radial}$ commute with each other?